# AWS EMR script-runner access error

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr, elastic-map-reduce

I'm running emr-5.12.0, with Amazon 2.8.3, Hive 2.3.2, Hue 4.1.0, Livy 0.4.0, Spark 2.2.1 and Zeppelin 0.7.3 on 1 m4.large as my master node and 1 m4.large as core node.

I am trying to execute a bootstrap action that configures some parts of the cluster. One of these includes the line:

```
sudo sed -i '/zeppelin.pyspark.python/c\      \"zepplin.pyspark.python\" : \"python3\",' /etc/alternatives/zeppelin-conf/interpreter.json
```

It makes sure that the Zeppelin uses python3.4 instead of python2.7. It works fine if I execute this in the terminal after SSH'ing to the master node, but it fails when I submit it as a Custom JAR step on the AWS Web interface.  I get the following error:

```
ed: can't read /etc/alternatives/zeppelin-conf/interpreter.json
: No such file or directory
Command exiting with ret '2'
```

The same thing happens if I use

```
sudo sed -i '/zeppelin.pyspark.python/c\      \"zepplin.pyspark.python\" : \"python3\",' /etc/zeppelin-conf/interpreter.json
```

Obviously I could just change it from the Zeppelin UI, but I would like to include it in the bootstrap action.

Thanks!

Comment: What are running - step or Bootstrap action where you are seeing this error? You are interchanging both in your problem description, can you please clarify? FYI Bootstrap Actions are run on all EMR nodes before EMR applications (hadoop, spark, zeppelin) are installed on the cluster whereas EMR steps are run only on master node after all EMR Applications are installed if it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm submitting a bootstrap action through the AWS EMR web interface when launching the cluster. It turns out that this is executed as regular EMR step when I export the AWS CLI command from the web interface.  So, I just have to use the CLI instead of the web interface to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a bootstrap action submitted throug the AWS EMR web interface is submitted as a regular EMR step, so it's only run on the master node. This can be seen if you click the 'AWS CLI export' in the cluster web interface. The intended bootstrap action is listed as a regular step. 
Using the command line to launch a cluster with a bootstrap action bypasses this problem, so I've just used that.

Edit: Looking back at the web interface, it's pretty clear that I was adding regular steps instead of bootstrap actions. My bad!